# Validate VAT number offline

Tags: c#, validation

I'm writing a small app with different inputs from a file (like countrycode, vat number etc) and I have to validate that the vat numbers are in the correct format.

I've tried this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/VATchecker.aspx - and it works.. but, and yes, there's always a but :-), I have to check anywhere from 100 - 500 vat numbers and it's just too slow for that. Besides, I'm not sure they appreciate me hammering their site like that.

Does anyone know of an offline vat-validater I can build into my C# program?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with optimizing the working code?

Comment: You mean the VATchecker-code, or?
According to VIES their system is designed for single-requests and not batch-requests.

Comment: Why don't you try running it on multiple threads. It doesn't help in not hammering, but might speed up your application by a factor 4 to 8.

Comment: 'Their site' is a web service designed for that purpose, isn't it? Question is: Does that service merely provide some kind of checksum verification or does it actually validate the number is in use? The latter can't be done algorithmically, so a web service call is required.

Comment: @Steven:
Guess I could try that. :-) edit: Although, I doubt it would help much. The response-time is just too long I think.
@mnemosyn:
Yes, it's designed to check one VAT number at a time. It validates each number and returns the address etc. I don't really need that - I just need to check if the format is correct (ie. DK has 8 chars, all numeric)

Comment: @Thomas: If you only care about the format, then the link in my answer specifies that for each member state.

Answer (score 11):

Based on @Uwe Keim's (outdated) Answer i made the regex'es for 2014 with these rules: http://www.bzst.de/DE/Steuern_International/USt_Identifikationsnummer/Merkblaetter/Aufbau_USt_IdNr.html?nn=23440

```
AT ^ATU[A-Z0-9]{8,8}$ 
BE ^BE[0-9]{10,10}$ 
BG ^BG[0-9]{9,9}$|^BG[0-9]{10,10}$
CY ^CY[0-9]{8,8}[A-Z]{1,1}$ 
CZ ^CZ[0-9]{8,10}$
DE ^DE[0-9]{9,9}$
DK ^DK[0-9]{8,8}$
EE ^EE[0-9]{9,9}$
ES ^ES[A-Z0-9]{1,1}[0-9]{7,7}[A-Z0-9]{1,1}$ 
FI ^FI[0-9]{8,8}$ 
FR ^FR[A-Z0-9]{2,2}[0-9]{9,9}$ 
GB ^GB[0-9]{9,9}$|^GB[0-9]{12,12}$|^GBGD[0-9]{3,3}$|^GBHA[0-9]{3,3}$ 
HU ^HU[0-9]{8,8}$ 
IE ^IE[0-9]{1,1}[A-Z0-9]{1,1}[0-9]{5,5}[A-Z]{1,1}$|^IE[0-9]{7,7}[A-W]{1,1}[A-I]{1,1}$ 
IT ^IT[0-9]{11,11}$ 
LT ^LT[0-9]{9,9}$|^LT[0-9]{12,12}$
LU ^LU[0-9]{8,8}$ 
LV ^LV[0-9]{11,11}$ 
MT ^MT[0-9]{8,8}$ 
NL ^NL[A-Z0-9]{9,9}B[A-Z0-9]{2,2}$ 
PL ^PL[0-9]{10,10}$   
PT ^PT[0-9]{9,9}$
SE ^SE[0-9]{10,10}01$
SI ^SI[0-9]{8,8}$
SK ^SK[0-9]{10,10}$
RO ^RO[1-9]{1,1}[0-9]{1,9}$
EL ^EL[0-9]{9,9}$ 
HR ^HR[0-9]{11,11}$
```

Someone may need it.

Comment: At least Romanian pattern is incorrect. The number's length could be from 2 to 10 digits. The correct pattern would be ^RO[1-9]{1,1}[0-9]{1,9}$.

Comment: There was no minimum defined for Romania where i looked so i assumed they'd just use all digits. I corrected it, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 9):

In our online shops, I'm doing it similar to the solution in the Code Project article.

Before submitting it to the web services I do a small regular expression sanity check to filter out "syntactially" wrong VAT IDs and therefore reduce the number of SOAP calls I have to perform.

This is an excerpt from the table I'm using to store the regular expressions, maybe this helps you, if you plan something similar:

```
Code2    VatIDRegex
----------------------------------------------------------
at       ^ATU[A-Z0-9]{8,8}$
be       ^BE[0-9]{9,9}$
cy       ^CY[0-9]{9,9}$
cz       ^CZ[0-9]{8,10}$
de       ^DE[0-9]{9,9}$
dk       ^DK[0-9]{8,8}$
ee       ^EE[0-9]{9,9}$
es       ^ES[A-Z0-9]{1,1}[0-9]{7,7}[A-Z0-9]{1,1}$
fi       ^FI[0-9]{8,8}$
fr       ^FR[A-Z0-9]{2,2}[0-9]{9,9}$
gb       ^GB[0-9]{9,9}$|^GB[0-9]{12,12}$|^GBGD[0-9]{3,3}$
hu       ^HU[0-9]{8,8}$
ie       ^IE[A-Z0-9]{8,8}$
it       ^IT[0-9]{11,11}$
lt       ^LT[0-9]{9,9}$|^LT[0-9]{12,12}$
lu       ^LU[0-9]{8,8}$
lv       ^LV[0-9]{11,11}$
mt       ^MT[0-9]{8,8}$
nl       ^NL[A-Z0-9]{9,9}B[A-Z0-9]{2,2}$
pl       ^PL[0-9]{10,10}$
pt       ^PT[0-9]{9,9}$
se       ^SE[0-9]{12,12}$
si       ^SI[0-9]{8,8}$
sk       ^SK[0-9]{10,10}$
```

Comment: i've created a gist from these regexes, updated with the corrections by @BigM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36942179/3057236

Comment: [This is the link to @geoforce's Gist](https://gist.github.com/gl005/e2e656d648a167ac6fed1a412975611c).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this http://code.google.com/p/vat-validation/
It's still work in progress but has the code for almost all the EU countries.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/faqvies.do#item5) site they do specify the structure of the VAT numbers for each of the member states. Possibly you could do a check for your numbers being in the correct structure first which might avoid having to do some of the requests.

Other than that, I think you will have to use this webservice to validate the numbers. The webservice does not link to a single database but rather connect to each state's database to verify the number, so there's no single database that you could download (maybe some states will have downloads of all valid VAT numbers that you could download, but I doubt it and you'd have to make sure that it's kept up to date etc).

As Steven suggests in his comment though, you might be able to speed it up by doing multiple requests at the same time. I wouldn't have thought that this would be a problem but you could always email the address mentioned in Q16 on that page and ask them if that is ok.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at that one. I would probably have to make a function to check each VAT-number against the format, based on the country-code.

Unfortunately I don't think looking up hundreds of VAT-numbers on their web-site is the best way to go. Would be much easier for me, but I guess I have to do it the hard way and check them manually to see if the format is correct :(

Comment: @Thomas: Well, depends on why you're doing this check. If you're going to sell something VATable and you don't charge VAT because the client gave you a VAT number, and then that VAT number was invalid, I think you could end up having to pay VAT that you never collected, so in that instance it might be worth using the webservice to check as carefully as possible.

Comment: That is true. I forgot to write, that the input-variables come from our Navision, so the VAT-numbers _should_ be valid. The problem is we have quite a few "placeholder"-entries in our Navision-databases, that are empty or have "NO VAT".

These are really the entries I need to check for. Our accounting-department check the VAT-numbers manually when they create customers. 

I know this might sound a bit confusing, but basically I was just wondering if anyone had writting a function that could validate the format of VAT-numbers, according to Q16 on VIES :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   if (vatNo.Length == 9)
            {
                int calcValue = 0;
                int index = 0;
                int checkDigit = Convert.ToInt32(vatNo.Substring(7, 2));

                for (int ordinate = 8; ordinate > 1; ordinate--)
                {
                    calcValue += Convert.ToInt32((vatNo.Substring(index, 1))) * ordinate;
                    index++;
                }
                while (calcValue > 0)
                {
                    calcValue -= 97;
                }
                if ((calcValue * -1) != checkDigit)
                {
                    Error
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option for you, you may use js-lib (my as well):

https://github.com/se-panfilov/jsvat

(jsvat check's VAT number twice - with regexp and with math calculation)